# get current language in flask appbuilder

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder, python-babel

I have a simple app wrote with Flask Appbuilder, the `view.py` is as follows. It is part of exmaple in http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html with a little change in `method1` where I replaced `return 'Hello'` with a function that I wish to find.

We can change the language in app (en,fr,ru,...) and translate it. Is there a function to get the current language? (Current_Language()).

```
from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, BaseView, expose, has_access, ModelView
from app import appbuilder, db
from flask import render_template, g
from flask_babel import Babel
from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _
from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.interface import SQLAInterface

class MyView(BaseView):    
  default_view = 'method1'    
  @expose('/method1/')
  @has_access
  def method1(self):
    return Current_Language()

appbuilder.add_view(MyView, "Method1", category='My View')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appbuilder` instance has a `bm` attribute, which is an instance of the `BabelManager` class.

This class has a `get_locale` method that returns the current language your app is using.

```
class MyView(BaseView):    
    default_view = 'method1'    
    @expose('/method1/')
    @has_access
    def method1(self):
        return appbuilder.bm.get_locale()
```

You can check the code for the `BabelManager` class on the [project repository.](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/babel/manager.py#L8)

Answer (score 1):

There is an ambiguity in your question. Do you mean the current server-side language or the client-side language.

The former:

```
import locale
locale.getlocale()
```

The latter:

```
from flask import request
request.headers.get('your-header-name')
```

The header you are interested in is `Accept-Language`. But there are caveats when it comes to inferring the client language that way. See https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales